# Why onReceive get call multiple time in froyo and not in JellyBean

Tags: java, android

i have my application install in 2 different phone
one with android 2.3.5 and another in 4.2.1
the problem is on the one with 2.3.5 onreceive get call everytime
but for the other phone the method got call once and never get call again.

I would like someone to explain me what cause android 4.2.1 not call onreceive multiple time.
Thank you.

```
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.v("ok","onreceive");
                    availableWifi = wifiManager.getScanResults(); // get all network
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(
                    WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
            wifiManager.startScan();
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what intent are you listening for?

Comment: i reedit my post by putting some code

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is rather because of the different implementations of the phone manufacturer over the custom OS.